# nginx reverse proxy websockets

Tags: nginx, websocket

nginx now supports proxying websockets, but I was unable to find any information on how to do this without having a separate *location* block that applies to URIs on which websockets are used.

I've seen some folks recommending some variations of this approach:

```
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection  "upgrade";

    proxy_pass  http://host:port;
}
```

Would that be the correct way to proxy standard HTTP as well as websockets?

I don't want the `Upgrade` header or `Connection` being set to `upgrade` unless that's what the browser sent, but these `proxy_set_header` lines are required for websockets to work.

Why doesn't nginx just forward the original Upgrade/Connection headers?

I've experimented with this and found that nginx does not proxy the `Upgrade` header and changes the `Connection` header to `close` from `upgrade` if running without the two `proxy_set_header` lines. With them, `Connection` is `upgrade` for non-websocket requests, which is also bad.

Comment: There seem to be a case mistprint in Nginx docs: 
`Connection: "Upgrade"`
finally worked for me, instead.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Why doesn't nginx just forward the original Upgrade/Connection headers?

From the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html): *since the “Upgrade” is a hop-by-hop header, it is not passed from a client to proxied server*

See [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.5.1).

---

> I don't want the Upgrade header or Connection being set to "upgrade" unless that's what the browser sent,

There is also an example:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    ...

    location /chat/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

---

> Connection is 'upgrade' for non-websocket requests, which is also bad.

Do you actually know what the `Connection` header means? Just a quote from RFC: *for each connection-token in this field, remove any header field(s) from the message with the same name as the connection-token.*

How it can be bad?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
For k8s nginx ingress configuration, I've used:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: prod-env
  name: core-backend
  labels:
    app: core-backend
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
      location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
```