# How to configure IPython behind nginx in a subpath?

Tags: nginx, proxy, websocket, ipython

I've got *nginx* running handling all SSL stuff and already proxying `/` to a *Redmine* instance and `/ci` to a *Jenkins* instance.

Now I want to serve an *IPython* instance on `/ipython` through that very same *nginx*.

In `nginx.conf` I've added:

```
http {
    ...
    upstream ipython_server {
        server 127.0.0.1:5001;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        ... # all SSL related stuff and the other proxy configs (Redmine+Jenkins)

        location /ipython {
            proxy_pass http://ipython_server;
        }
    }
}
```

In my `.ipython/profile_nbserver/ipython_notebook_config.py` I've got:

```py
c.NotebookApp.base_project_url = '/ipython/'
c.NotebookApp.base_kernel_url = '/ipython/'
c.NotebookApp.port = 5001
c.NotebookApp.trust_xheaders = True
c.NotebookApp.webapp_settings = {'static_url_prefix': '/ipython/static/'}
```

---

Pointing my browser to `https://myserver/ipython` gives me the usual index page of all notebooks in the directory I launched *IPython*.
However, when I try to open one of the existing notebooks or create a new one, I'm getting the error:

**WebSocket connection failed**: *A WebSocket connection to could not be established. You will NOT be able to run code. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.*

I've tried the same setup with the current stable (1.2.1, via pypi) and development (Git checkout of master) version of *IPython*.
I also tried adjusting the *nginx* config according to [nginx reverse proxy websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15193743/588243) with no avail.
Due to an enforced policy I'm not able to allow connections to the server on other ports than 443.

Does anybody have *IPython* running behind an *nginx*?

Comment: What version of NGINX are you using?

Comment: I just had the exact same problem on my Ubuntu server.  I was running Ubuntu 12.04 and the version of NGINX was 1.1.19.  Looking around it seemed like the websockets proxy forwarding didn't get sorted out until 1.3.something in NGINX.  So I followed this guide: http://usefulmix.com/install-upgrade-to-latest-nginx-without-compiling-from-source/ to get NGINX upgraded (in my case I'm now running 1.5.13).  Everything worked perfectly afterwards.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem. I updated nginx up to the current version (1.6.0). It seems to be working now.

Server config:

```
location /ipython {
    proxy_pass http://ipython_server;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Origin "";
}
```

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Comment: I had to add `proxy_set_header  Origin  "";` to make this work. The Tornado server doesn't accept connections otherwise since the origin check doesn't pass.

Comment: ^^^ this comment is crucial!

Comment: So how I do I handle the case where I need the `Origin` header passed through since I'm doing cross-domain calls?

Comment: I don't know why, but this worked for me as well. Everything in my config can be followed from the docs but I was still getting 404 when accessing the notebook until I made the changes to my nginx config

Comment: still valid today