# IPython notebook WebSocket connection could not be established. You will NOT be able to run code

Tags: python, websocket, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've been tryin to run some simple code in IPython notebook but i keep getting this error:
"A WebSocket connection could not be established. You will NOT be able to run code. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

There were no problems during the install and there are no error messeges when i load the notebook.

I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the fact im running my local server on xamp?

Doed anyone have a clue how to solve this?

I would be very greatfull.

Edit: I'm loading my notebook using the command 'ipython notebook' in the command prompet the output is:

```
[NotebookApp]"Using existing profile dir: c:\users\Nimrod\.ipython\profile_default
[NotebookApp]using MathJax from CDN: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/mathjax.js
[NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory c:\users\Nimrod
[NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[NotebookApp] use control c to stop server and shut doen all kernels
[NotebookApp] Kernel started: 0ac0db12-63a0-4a4a-be25-0051
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to give folks some more info I think.  How are you launching ipython notebook?  Do you have any console output you can include here?

Comment: Okay, I assume you're trying to access this on port 80 where you have `xamp` running?  To do that you'll want to look into running ipython behind apache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890386/how-to-run-ipython-behind-an-apache-proxy

Comment: which browser do you use ?

Comment: chrome the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, by default `ipython notebook` launches standalone using the `tornado` http server running on local port 8888.

Try typing `localhost:8888` into your browser.

If you want to customize it to run on a different port use:

```
ipython notebook --port=<NEW PORT>
```

If you'd also like to allow connections from remote machines do:

```
ipython notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=<NEW PORT>
```

Comment: Hey mike, i've tried entering localhost:888 and nothing happens. As for to customize the port how do i know which port to use? which is available? I hope it is clear i'm a novice in Ipython.

Comment: localhost:8888 not localhost:888