# Notebook behind apache proxy

Tags: apache, jupyter-notebook, mod-proxy

I'm trying to run [iPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) behind an Apache2 proxy and I'm having trouble with WebSockets.

I'd like to have the notebook accessible from ***<domain>*/python/**.

Using a few tutorials and the apache wiki, I managed to write this `VirtualHosts` file:

```
# Trying to proxy WS requests
ProxyPass /python/api/kernels ws://127.0.0.1:8888/python/api/kernels
ProxyPassReverse /python/api/kernels ws://127.0.0.1:8888/python/api/kernels

# Proxy HTTP requests
ProxyPass /python http://127.0.0.1:8888/python
ProxyPassReverse /python http://127.0.0.1:8888/python
ProxyRequests On

# Spoof headers only if the URL contains "/python/" (I have other stuff on this VHost)
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /python/">
   Header set Host "http://127.0.0.1:8888/python"
   Header set Origin "http://127.0.0.1:8888/python"

   RequestHeader set Host "http://127.0.0.1:8888/python"
   RequestHeader set Origin "http://127.0.0.1:8888/python"
</If>
```

Here's my notebook profile config:

```
c = get_config()

c.NotebookApp.ip = '127.0.0.1'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888

c.NotebookApp.base_url = '/python/'
c.NotebookApp.tornado_settings = {'static_url_prefix':'/python/static/'}
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin='http://127.0.0.1:8888/python'
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/home/franga2000/iPython/'
```

I'm getting this error in the NB console (also for `/stdin` and `/iopub`:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:400 GET /python/api/kernels/f2d21678-4fef-4cb4-996f-dcee954b54ca/shell (127.0.0.1) 0.44ms referer=None
```

I'm using Apache **2.4.7** on Ubuntu **14.04**.
Also, the notebook is runing in a virtualenv (doubt its relevant).

Does anyone know a way to do this (without switching to nginx)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Not the first time something like this was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890386/how-to-run-ipython-behind-an-apache-proxy and even the official website recommend SO for support

Comment: No, but this question was on the homepage while I was cleaning it up. If the question you cited is off-topic, then you should flag it as such. Or maybe this question is a duplicate of that question ;)

Comment: Both of these questions are completely on topic and they are not the same.

Comment: Finally found a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28819231/1906127