# ipython server can't launch: No module named notebook.notebookapp

Tags: python, server, ipython

I've been trying to setup an ipython server following several tutorials (since none was exactly my case). A couple days ago, I did manage to get it to the point where it was launching but then was not able to access it via url. Today it's not launching anymore and I can't find much about this specific error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==4.0.0-dev', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-4.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-4.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 302, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-4.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/application.py", line 386, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython-4.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 297, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/traitlets/config/application.py", line 487, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets-4.0.0-py2.7.egg/traitlets/config/application.py", line 418, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp
```

So about the setup, I have installed the anaconda distrib of ipython, pyzmq & tornado libraries. I have created a profile nbserver and the config file is as follows - ipython.config.py:

```
c = get_config()
c.IPKernalApp.pylab = 'inline'
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ludo/.ipython/profile_nbserver/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:e6cb2aa9a[...]'
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
c.NotebookManager.notebook_dir = u'/var/www/ipynb/'
c.NotebookApp.base_project_url = '/ipynb/'
c.NotebookApp.base_kernel_url = '/ipynb/'
c.NotebookApp.webapp_settings = {'static_url_prefix':'/ipynb/static/'}
```

I really don't know where to look for clues anymore - and I'm probably lacking a greater understanding of how all this works to figure it out. My ultimate goal is to then use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890386/how-to-run-ipython-behind-an-apache-proxy) on SO to complete a setup behind apache and eventually connect it to colaboratory - but seems like it should launch first.

Many thanks for any help :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is requesting help to install a developement version of a software, while it should stick to stable version.

Comment: Please select @AndySmith's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32166022/210945), so it floats to the top, as it is more correct.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This should fix the issue:

```
pip install jupyter
```

Comment: aaah! this is AWESOME! thanks a lot, i could've lost hours without ur answer

Comment: If you use Anaconda: launch Anaconda prompt as admin (if you're on Windows), then `conda update conda && conda update ipython && conda install jupyter`.

Comment: jupyter is more and more the tool to use when you want to work with notebooks via ipython.  See http://ipython.org for the long story.

Comment: I am trying to `pip install jupyter`, but i get this error: `No distributions at all found for entrypoints (from nbconvert->jupyter)`

Answer (score 20):

I received the same problem when upgrading IPython. At the moment the answer was written, it was a bug linked to the latest `4` version. If a similar problem occurs for which you wish to switch back to the stable version `3.2.1`:

```
pip uninstall -y IPython
pip install ipython==3.2.1
```

- note: the `-y` option indicates "yes I want to uninstall" with no interaction.
- note 2: possible duplicate in [ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401890/importerror-no-module-named-notebook-notebookapp)

Comment: Hi Meduz, yes, I followed a tutorial blindly and didn't realise I installed a dev version via git... strange for Microsoft to suggest this install to make your DS environment... Anyhow, I uninstalled, modified my shell path to be able to use the anaconda instance (which I had also installed), opened my port on my firewall conf file and finally managed to get all this up & running... phew! After all, it's by screwing up that you really learn :)

Comment: For clarification, I was able to get this to work for what I wanted when I did:



`pip install ipython[notebook]==3.2.1`

Comment: -1: this isn't a bug in iPython per se; it's simply that it doesn't force you to install the dependencies for the `notebook` command (and the exact same thing happens in 3.2, just with a slightly more informative error message). The above comment has the correct solution.

Comment: To expand on @DaveC and @Ben's point, simply running `pip install ipython[notebook]` solves the issue using the latest version of ipython notebook.

Comment: I updated the wording to reflect that this "bug" was fixed until the point the question was asked - and by the way, note that now jupyter is here, see http://blog.jupyter.org/2015/08/12/first-release-of-jupyter/

Comment: Given that @AndySmith's answer is generally more applicable and correct from now on, you should probably make it explicit that this isn't the recommended solution for the general problem, or just delete this answer.

Comment: This is not a big, the issue is still present with the stable version, but it's only logical because IPython is now a wrapper for Jupyter for Python, so you now need to install both.

Answer (score 4):

So to close this thread, and in case it helps anyone, my mistake was to have installed and used the dev version of ipython blindly following a tutorial, thinking I was using the anaconda instance I installed earlier (which was not even in my PATH).

Anyhow I:

- uninstalled that ipython dev instance
- added anaconda/bin to my zsh path (add it to ~/.zshrc - that's why it was not even in my path after install) // *at this point the server was launching fine but I couldn't access it in my browser >> firewall problems.*
- opened my port of choice in my firewall (help for [linode](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server#creating-a-firewall) or [ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) in general)

And everything works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Someone mentioned this in a comment, and it (almost) worked for me:

```
pip install ipython[notebook]
```

`pip` gave an error about the hash not matching. However, what ultimately worked was:

```
sudo port install py27-notebook
```

And for py3:

```
sudo port install py35-notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to install from github master branch if you do not now what you are doing. Remove what you have installed and stick to stable version.

If you want to work on developpement version, ask on the developpement mailing-list. Some knowlege on how to debug this will probably be required.

Comment: quite right @Matt, did not notice I was installing a dev version following this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hpctrekker/archive/2013/04/09/data-science-in-a-box-using-ipython-installing-ipython-notebook-2-4.aspx)... I will uninstall that and try again cleanly, thanks.