# SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER when setting up public Juypter server

Tags: ssl, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm in the process of setting up a Juypter server to host my notebooks on.

In `/home/user/.jupyter/notebook_configuration.py`

```
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/user/.jupyter/mycert.pem'
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = u'/home/user/.jupyter/mykey.key'
```

And if I ran on the console

```
jupyter notebook --ip="ip_address" --port=8000 --certfile=mycert.pem --keyfile mykey.key
```

The server and the certificate worked!

However, when I set up a DNS entry and attempt to route to the server I ran into this error

```
SSL Error on 10 ('ip_address', 63748): [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:600)
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is a super simple one that took me longer to figure out than it really should have.

By default the address that the console gives you is a `https` address to route to. `https` works.

But if you enter

```
your_url.com
```

it'll take you to `http://your_url.com`. If you set up TSL certs for your server your http routes don't work anymore and Jupyter doesn't come with a reroute to `https` out of the box.

**Work Around**: use https instead

**My Long Term Solution**: [I ended up hosting my Jupyter notebook behind apache.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890386/how-to-run-ipython-behind-an-apache-proxy)

Comment: Worked perfect, just want to add that your browser might warn you that the connection is not private if you use https://... but as long as you don't mind you can ignore that warning.

Comment: This saved me potentially an hour of googling around for a solution. Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't understand the solution. What needs to be changed? 

I believe I have the same issue. When I put in the propped notebook link, e.g. https://0.0.0.0:8888/, Safari/Chrome won't let me bypass certificate concerns to load the page. And I get a SSL error message as OP.

Comment: `0.0.0.0:8888` is probably a shorthand for `http://0.0.0.0:8888`. Try typing in explicitly `https://0.0.0.0:8888`