# Google drive multythreading move files PYTHON

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

Sorry fro my englihs. I use pyDryve for google drive api. And i want move files from one folder to another, use for this multythreading.

```
        pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
# i have list of file
 for file in date_val:
                    pool.submit(self.start_rename_move_process, file)


def start_rename_move_process(self, file):
    try:
        print(file['title'])

        # Retrieve the existing parents to remove
        move_file = thread_drive.g_drive.auth.service.files().get(fileId=file['id'],
                                                          fields='parents').execute()

        previous_parents = ",".join([parent["id"] for parent in move_file.get('parents')])

        # Move the file to the new folder
        thread_drive.g_drive.auth.service.files().update(fileId=file['id'],
                                                       addParents=MOVE_FOLDER_ID,
                                                       removeParents=previous_parents,
                                                       fields='id, parents').execute()

    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)
```

i have error:

```
[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2217)
```

My question: Why in one thread all works fine, but if i do 2 thread i have error

```
[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2217)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL: WRONG\_VERSION\_NUMBER when setting up public Juypter server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345605/ssl-wrong-version-number-when-setting-up-public-juypter-server)

Comment: @DaImTo man, it looks like, but not that. I work with google drive sdk and cant understand why in one thread all works fine, but if i do 2 thread i have error

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same error recently, it turned out to be a problem with the httplib2 library as explained in this [thread safety](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/thread_safety.md) guide by google.

> The google-api-python-client library is built on top of the httplib2
> library, which is not thread-safe. Therefore, if you are running as a
> multi-threaded application, each thread that you are making requests
> from must have its own instance of httplib2.Http()

The guide provided two solutions for this problem:

> The easiest way to provide threads with their own httplib2.Http()
> instances is to either override the construction of it within the
> service object or to pass an instance via the http argument to method
> calls.

```
# Create a new Http() object for every request
def build_request(http, *args, **kwargs):
    new_http = httplib2.Http()
    return apiclient.http.HttpRequest(new_http, *args, **kwargs)
service = build('api_name', 'api_version', requestBuilder=build_request)

# Pass in a new Http() manually for every request
service = build('api_name', 'api_version')
http = httplib2.Http()
service.stamps().list().execute(http=http)
```

Comment: Note that the thread safety guide has moved to: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/thread_safety.md