# iPython/Jupyter Notebook Server behind Apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run my [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) Notebook server behind [Apache2](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html).

I am doing this on an OpenStack server with an IP of *192.x.x.1* and a floating IP of *85.x.x.1*. My domain name is (of the form) *notebook.project.company.org* and the hostname is *jupyter-notebook*, so `/etc/hosts` has the following

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 jupyter-notebook
```

I have setup the Jupyter server as described [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html) and this is reachable at *notebook.project.company.org:888** but I want to access it at *notebook.project.company.org*.

I am trying to do this using Apache and I tried to follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890386/how-to-run-ipython-behind-an-apache-proxy/24659720#24659720) but I'm getting confused between when to use domain/localhost/127.0.0.1/192.x.x.1 etc.

Currently my `jupyter_notebook_config.py` has

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '192.x.x.1'
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

and the apache conf file has

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName notebook.project.company.org
    ProxyPass / http://192.x.x.1:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.x.x.1:8888/
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone shed some light on exactly what IP addresses I should be using, and where?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I've configured an iPython Notebook behind an Apache before, but I have configured Tomcat servers behind it. I'd assume that it would be similar here.

For the ProxyPass I used the 127.0.0.1 IPs to map to the tomcat servers running on different port. You could try the same.