# ipython notebook server SSL error

Tags: ssl, nginx, ipython, reverse-proxy

I have an SSL certificate for my server (its a .crt bundle) but I keep getting errors when trying to use it with ipython notebook server

I have nginx setup in windows. Access to ipython is setup via a reverse proxy. I followed this here thread here: [How to configure IPython behind nginx in a subpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665809/how-to-configure-ipython-behind-nginx-in-a-subpath)

I followed the instructions on [how to set up a notebook server](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server). I'm also using the /ipython prefix. I changed the location of my certificate, which is a `.crt` file and not a `.pem`, everything else is left the same (besides password).

Whenever I try to access www.domain.com/ipython, I get this error:

```
[W 03:43:22.463 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 916 ('127.0.0.1', 1586): [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:581)

[E 03:43:22.463 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 693,
 in _server_request_loop
        ret = yield conn.read_response(request_delegate)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 870, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 215, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 876, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 168, in _read_message
        quiet_exceptions=iostream.StreamClosedError)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 870, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 215, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
    SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:581)
```

Everythings works on the local machine if I use a self-signed certificate, but it doesn't work remotely. And using a signed certificate does not work locally or remotely, and gives me the error above. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been solved. I was blindly following the instructions in the ipython doc, without realizing I should just have nginx handle all SSL connections, and ipython should not be set up to use SSL in the first place